# RecyclerView not updating the data

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, recyclerview-layout

I have a problem with updating the RecyclerView data, i guess there is something wrong with notifyDataSetChanged(), but i have no idea what.
The RecyclerView is just empty once created and nothing is changing.

Here is my code:

```
EditFriends2 (once i have it working i erase the "2" ;) )

public class EditFriendsActivty2 extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String TAG = EditFriendsActivty2.class.getSimpleName();
private ParseUser mCurrentUser;
private ParseRelation<ParseUser> mFriendsRelation;
private List<ParseUser> mFriends;
private List<ParseUser> mUsers;
private FriendsAdapter adapter;

private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit_friends_activty2);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    adapter = new FriendsAdapter(mUsers, mFriends);

    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(EditFriendsActivty2.this);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    showFriendsList();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    showFriendsList();
}

private void showFriendsList() {
    mCurrentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
    mFriendsRelation = mCurrentUser.getRelation(ParseConstants.KEY_FRIENDS_RELATION);

    ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();
    query.orderByAscending(ParseConstants.KEY_USERNAME);
    query.setLimit(1000);
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseUser> list, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                // Success
                mUsers = list;
                downloadFriends();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(EditFriendsActivty2.this, R.string.error_toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.i(TAG, e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    });
}

private void downloadFriends() {
    mFriendsRelation.getQuery().findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseUser> list, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                mFriends = list;

                 // Here i'm updating the RecyclerView, when i have the data about users and friends

                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            } else {
                Log.i(TAG, e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    });
}
}
```

My adapter:

```
public class FriendsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<FriendsAdapter.FriendsViewHolder> {

private static final String TAG = FriendsAdapter.class.getSimpleName();

private List<ParseUser> mUsers;
private List<ParseUser> mFriends;


public FriendsAdapter(List<ParseUser> users, List<ParseUser> friends){
    mUsers = users;
    mFriends = friends;
}


@Override
public FriendsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate((R.layout.friends_list_item), parent, false);
    FriendsViewHolder viewHolder = new FriendsViewHolder(view);
    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(FriendsViewHolder holder, int position) {
    if(mUsers != null) {
        holder.bindFriends(mUsers.get(position));
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return 0;
}

public class FriendsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public TextView mNameLabel;
    public CheckBox mCheckBox;

    public FriendsViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        mNameLabel = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.nameLabel);
        mCheckBox = (CheckBox) itemView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
    }

    public void bindFriends (ParseUser user){
        mNameLabel.setText(user.getUsername());
        mCheckBox.setChecked(false);

        for (ParseUser friend : mFriends){
                if(friend.getObjectId().equals(user.getObjectId())){
                    mCheckBox.setChecked(true);
                    break;
                }
        }
    }
}

}
```

Can anyone help me to fix it? Thanks in adavance!

Comment: There are two problems here. The reason it is always empty is because you've set `getItemCount()` to return 0. The reason it won't be updated is because you are changing the friends list inside the activity, not inside the adapter. See my answer for the solution to each.

Comment: Don't forget to accept an answer if it ends up helping you, @Yogurt33

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are never actually changing the Adapter's list. Look at this line inside the `Activity` class:

```
mFriendsRelation.getQuery().findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
    @Override
    public void done(List<ParseUser> list, ParseException e) {
        if (e == null) {
            mFriends = list;

             // Here i'm updating the RecyclerView, when i have the data about users and friends

            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        } else {
            Log.i(TAG, e.getMessage());
        }
    }
});
```

The `mFriends` object that you are setting is a variable inside the Activity, it is not the same as the one inside the Adapter. I'd recommend adding a method like this in your adapter:

```
public void swapFriends(List<ParseUser> friends) {
   mFriends = friends;
   notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Then you can call it inside your `findInBackground()` method like this:

```
mFriendsRelation.getQuery().findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
    @Override
    public void done(List<ParseUser> list, ParseException e) {
        if (e == null) {
            adapter.swapFriends(list);
        } else {
            Log.i(TAG, e.getMessage());
        }
    }
});
```

**EDIT:** Another problem probably lies in your `getItemCount()` method. You are always returning 0. You need to return the number of friends you want to display. Change it to:

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mFriends.size();
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I totally missed the getItemCount() method. Now it works perfectly

Answer (score 1):

Initially when creating the `FriendsAdapter` your `mFriends` and `mUsers` lists are `null` ?

When you receive the data response you are replacing your current `mUsers` and `mFriends` lists with new references. While the RecyclerView will keep pointing to the old lists.

**Solution 1:**

Make sure `mFriends` and `mUsers` are not `null` to begin with.

You can then do `mFriends.addAll(newFriends)` and `mUsers.addAll(newUsers)` to add the new friends and users once received. Then perform the `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`

**Solution 2:**

Add a method in your `FriendsAdapter` to tell the RecyclerView that you have a new list `adapter.showNewFriends(mFriends)`. Add users if you need those as another parameter or another method call when you fetch them first. In this adapter method you could then call `notifyDataSetChanged()`.